# Integration tests create test users on Stripe, how to stop or stub out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber, integration-testing, stripe-payments

I'm using stripe on a project. I'm using Railscasts #288 (http://railscasts.com/episodes/288-billing-with-stripe) as a guide. I have it so that once a user registers with a valid username and password I will create their Stripe customer account.

After a few runs of my integration test I can see that I have many users created in my test account for Stripe. How do I structure the integration test so that it goes through my registration process as a typical user would, but without creating the Stripe account with Stripe?

Comment: I'd just create a new user each time, and clear all test data periodically

Answer (score 5):

I'm coming a little late to the game, but check out [StripeMock](https://github.com/rebelidealist/stripe-ruby-mock). It is made specifically for this purpose.

```
StripeMock.start
Stripe::Customer.create({
  id: '123',
  email: 'someone@something.com',
  card: 'void_card_token',
  subscriptions: {
    data: [{
      plan: {
        name: 'Some Subscription Plan',
        currency: 'usd',
        amount: 1000
      },
      start: 1410408211,
      status: 'active',
      current_period_start: 1410408211,
      current_period_end: 1413000211
    }]
  }
})

test... test... test...
StripeMock.stop
```

Answer (score 3):

i dealt with that by making all my customers created through the testing have "deletable" in their email address, and adding these lines to my spec_helper.

```
config.after(:suite) do
  custs = Stripe::Customer.all(limit: 100).data
  custs.keep_if { |c| c.email.match( /deletable/ )  }
  custs.each { |c| c.delete }
end
```

Comment: worth noting, a stripe employee told me they expect their clients to want to test directly. so while ordinarily it might be bad form to have your specs hit the actual api, stripe assumes you will do so.

Answer (score 2):

This is typically done with a tool like [WebMock](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock) which intercepts the HTTP request and returns a response you provide. The [VCR](https://github.com/vcr/vcr) gem makes this process easier by recording and replaying HTTP requests using WebMock (or optionally FakeWeb) under the hood. There is a Railscast on VCR, but it is a bit out of date. Take care not to record any sensitive data (i.e. api keys) by using the [`filter_sensitive_data`](https://www.relishapp.com/vcr/vcr/v/2-4-0/docs/configuration/filter-sensitive-data!) configuration option.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to really test an integration without making your tests as realistic as possible. Therefore, I suggest that you let stripe create the test customer accounts, but make use of the webhooks to automatically delete them.

Specifically, you would handle the customer.created event. If event->livemode == false, send a request back to the api to delete the customer.

This way, you run through the entire process as you test, while only keeping customers that were created in live mode.